# Rails issue with rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

so I'm new to rails and currently going through a tutorial for it on tutorialspoint. What I've gotten so far is a controller and a corresponding view for it which is an erb file. This is the code for the view:

```
<% if @books.blank? %>
<p>There are not any books currently in the system.</p>
<% else %>
<p>These are the current books in our system</p>

<ul id = "books">
   <% @books.each do |c| %>
   <li><%= link_to c.title, {:action => 'show', :id => c.id} -%></li>
   <% end %>
</ul>

<% end %>
<p><%= link_to "Add new Book", {:action => 'new' }%></p>
```

However, when I try to view this through localhost:3000 while having the

```
rails server
```

command running a WEBrick server in the background on localhost:3000,
it keeps directing me to the default view on my browser,which is being rendered by the server from the following path:

/Users/hassanali/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb

instead of the actual view within my rails application folder's view folder..which is

/Users/hassanali/Desktop/library/app/views/book/list.html.erb

I've been trying to fix this for ages now and no avail. Does anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you not define `root_path` for your app.

In `config/routes.rb` define `root_path` for it, ex:

```
root 'book#list'
```

Comment: Cheers dude! Worked ! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can tell Rails what you want '/' to route to by using `root controller#action`.

For example say you had a controller that looked like this.

```
class BooksController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    @books = Books.all
  end

  def show
    @book = Books.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

If you wanted '/' to route to your `index` method, you would do the following in `config/routes.rb`.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'books#index'

  # Other routes here...

end
```

As a side note, if you add two `root` method calls, it will use the last one in the routes file.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root

Since you have `show` and `new` action referenced you'll also likely want those routes as well. It's recommended to use RESTful routing schemes. Rails provides a useful method called `resources` which creates all the routes and helper methods needed to CRUD a resource.

That might look like the following.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'books#index'

  # A books resource
  resources :books

end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

I encourage you to read the Rails Guide on routing so you understand your options.